# What is a legal and allowed method of getting a picture from Internet to be used in the cover of my thesis?

Tags: thesis, graphics

I need a picture from the Internet of micro bacterium which I want to use on my Thesis cover. Now just coping the picture and using it will be like stealing someone else's property. Hence I want to know if there is any proper and legal method by which I can get the picture. [This is the picture](http://www.bioquell.asia/interface/assets/images/content/Mycobacterium_tuberculosis_14313982.jpg) that I need, I wrote them a mail too but no reply yet.

Comment: The providence of your picture is rather unclear; it seems to have been propagated quite a bit without attribution on the internet. (The link you pasted may or may not be the original provider of the image.) You are much better off first picking a trusted provider (Wikimedia commons or [PHIL](http://phil.cdc.gov/phil/home.asp) for example) and then choosing the images from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask the author of the image, or the owner of the exclusive licence if that is a different person, for permission to use the image. He may or may not grant it.

If he grants you permission for free then it is courtesy to write an acknowledgement to that effect somewhere in the thesis.

If the image is in the public domain then of course you are free to do with it as you will. (By "public domain", I mean, free of copyright restrictions by the explicit choice of the author or because the image is so old it can no longer be subject to copyright. I do not mean, simply the image was found in public.)

However many institutions have precise binding requirements for theses which would not allow you to place artwork on the cover (even if you already had licence to do so from the author). You should confirm with your institution whether this would be allowed.

Comment: If the image is in the public domain, then *legally* you are free to do with it as you will, but according to *academic ethics* you still need to acknowledge the creator and/or source where you got it.

Comment: There is a third option that you do not cover, but in my opinion it is the most common solution: using (with proper acknowledgment) an image with a liberal license such as Creative Commons.

Comment: Or you can use similar image from a journal paper and ask for copyright to the journal editor. If it is only one image, I believe the cost would be zero, but you need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could just go to a commercial site like shutterstock.com, find an image you like and license it. It's not free, but in the UK the cheapest purchase is five images for £32. The license seems to allow your usage; if you intend to print 100,000 copies of your thesis you better check it carefully. And yes, they have a few images of a tuberculosis bacterium available.

That's the copyright side of things, obviously you need to check if there are any requirements from an academic point of view.